# 400 (Bad Request) for http.post() with request body - Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-http

I want to get token code when I post user data. But, Server response to me as 400 Bad Request.

```
POST http://xxx/api/auth 400 (Bad Request)
```

I can get token code with Postman

My AuthService

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Token } from './token';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  api = 'http://xxx/api/auth';
  token;

  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
  }

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  login(user):Observable<Token>{
    this.http.post<Token>(this.api, JSON.stringify(user), this.httpOptions).subscribe(
      res => {
        localStorage.setItem('token', res.token)
      },
      err => console.log(err)
    )
  }

}
```

My Login Component

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  loginUserData = {}

  constructor(
    private auth: AuthService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  Login(){
    this.auth.login(this.loginUserData);
  }

}
```

Please help me what i am missing. I tried to pass the data in stringfy format but that is also giving me same error.

Comment: what CORS settings do you have on your server?

Comment: I am seeing empty payload in your code snippet. Is it intended?

Comment: defaults:
    allow_credentials: false
    allow_origin: ['*']
    allow_headers: ['*']
    allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE']
    expose_headers: []
    max_age: 0
    hosts: []
    origin_regex: false
paths:
    '^/api/auth':
        allow_origin: ['*']
        allow_headers: ['*']
        allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE']
        max_age: 3600

Comment: What are you saying about empty payload. Can you explain it.